# Transforming an array using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

how would I transform this array :

```
[["10"], ["20"], ["30"], ["40"], ["21"], ["31"], ["41"], ["32"], ["42"], ["43"]]
```

into this array

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [2, 1], [3 1,], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Ideally in the most beginner friendly version possible please.
I'm failing to iterate through the array thoroughly and use the correct methods in the correct order.

Comment: "I'm failing" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Each element in your array is another array containing one string. It's probably this extra nesting that makes it hard to convert it. May I ask why your array looks like this instead for example simply `["10", "20", "30", ...]`? Where does your array come from?

Comment: Apologies Jörg, I now understand the stackoverflow format - this was my first post.

Comment: The array comes from a Codewars challenge.  The reason I wanted it in the format I asked is because the challenge asks you to analyse football scores i.e. [1, 0] is 1 : 0 win to the team on the left.

Comment: @wanderingnowhere can you provide a link to the challenge?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5bb904724c47249b10000131

Comment: @wanderingnowhere note that the array in the challenge is `["3:1", "2:2", "0:1", ...]` whereas your array would be `[["31"], ["22"], ["01"], ...]`. Seems like you somehow removed the delimiting colons (could result in ambiguous values) and put every string in an extra array (makes it harder to process). Try to work on the original array.

Answer (score 5):

If the input is always as in your example (an array of arrays, where every array has a single element which is a string) then you can map to get the chars and then map that result to get them as integers;

```
[["10"], ["20"], ["30"], ["40"], ["21"], ["31"], ["41"], ["32"], ["42"], ["43"]]
  .map { |str, _| str.chars.map(&:to_i) }
# [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```